# SQL query to sort table by sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have basically following table:

id (int) username (string) messsage (string)  rating (int)

So the entries look like this:

```
1   thomas   "hello..."   3
2   Tina     "blabla"     2
3   thomas   "blub"       1
4   julia    "basgs"      3
```

...

I want retrieve the top 10 usernames with the most ratings for all their messages.
So I want to sort the table that it looks

```
1. thomas 4
2. julia 3
3. Tina 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sue I understood your question right, but try that one:

```
SELECT
    username,
    SUM(rating)
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    username
ORDER BY
    SUM(rating) desc
LIMIT
    10
```

Comment: Thx, its exactly what I was tryring to do!

Answer (score 0):

```
select  username
,       count(*)
from    YourTable
group by
        username
order by
        count(*) desc
limit   10
```

Comment: Why are you taking a count if he wants the `sum`?

Comment: @Evan: The question says `the most ratings`.  I agree that the example data looks like the `sum of ratings`.

Comment: I was just going off the title